# User invite system

Tags: looking-for-a-script

What is a good invite system that allows users to request an invite to their email address and get one send automatically after some days?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a place to ask for this kind of answer, but here goes:

http://drupal.org/project/requestinvitation

http://www.jomsocial.com/download/addons/core-enhancements/invitex-viral-invitations-system-for-joomla-jomsocial-a-cb.html

Just a few of a quick Google.